# Is A unsatisfiable if there is a completed tableau with all branches closed?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, young-tableaux

I am having troubles wrapping my head around unsatisfiability and satisfiability. I understand that A is said to be satisfiable if there exists at least one case where the formula A is true. But when it comes to tableaux i don't understand how conclusions are drawn with regards to unsatisfiability. I understand the mechanism of it but cant draw conclusions. I would appreciate any help or guidance. If you could provide an answer and example to the question it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, A is indeed unsatisfiable if there is a completed tableau with all branches closed!

For a longer answer which explains why, check out the opening pages of  [these notes on (propositional) truth-trees](https://www.logicmatters.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/TruthTreesPL1.pdf).

(These notes form a freely available appendix to the second ed. of my *[Introduction to Formal Logic](https://www.logicmatters.net/ifl/ifl2nd/)*. The main text is natural-deduction based, but this appendix covers tableaux as an alternative proof system.)